# how to call java method in jsp

Tags: java

Hi i am writing a code to extract twitter info.The normal java code is working  but when i call it using jsp, its gives error.
i am using eclipse ide. i have also added twitter4j jar file.
i am using tomcat server

the error is
http 404
resource not available

i am uploading the codes.
i would me very grateful if u can help

**java code**

```
package com.test;
import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class TwitterTagAnalysis {
public void Test() throws TwitterException {
    ConfigurationBuilder cf = new ConfigurationBuilder();

   cf.setDebugEnabled(true)
           .setOAuthConsumerKey("ofmn2QuWUgRFmrvN3Hh5xcKHG")
           .setOAuthConsumerSecret("CjRjqHIFpuJY04IuiyvxqEFaaNnJnYRQ5UriH3VQSsKkz1FIvN")
           .setOAuthAccessToken("3281529866-jaLXqHoKzb1QsKDrBBuhGfYkfuTWf6Grwgd2iAA")
           .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("AjSp4wVvKmdtmLe7BJL6TupBQEmbfddTToK0O5pqQLQR5");

   TwitterFactory tf =  new TwitterFactory(cf.build());

   twitter4j.Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    twitter4j.Twitter twitter1 =  TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    Query query = new Query("#aprilfoolsday").lang("en");
    query.setCount(100);
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    for (Status status1 : result.getTweets()) {

        if(status1.isRetweet()){
            //status1.getRetweetedStatus().getText();
            System.out.println(status1.getUser().getName()+"->"+status1.getMediaEntities());

            System.out.println(status1.getUser().getName()+"->"+status1.getRetweetedStatus().getText());
            //System.out.println(status1.getGeoLocation());
            System.out.println("\n\n");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println(status1.getUser().getName()+"->"+status1.getMediaEntities());

        System.out.println(status1.getUser().getName()+"->"+status1.getText());
        //System.out.println(status1.getGeoLocation());
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        }
    }
    }

}
```

**jsp code**

```
<%@ page import="com.test.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
TwitterTagAnalysis ob = new TwitterTagAnalysis();
ob.Test();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, 404 is not really a java/jsp error. Tomcat just tells you that the url you are using to access your JSP is wrong, so you need to use the right url.

Comment: Unless you import the `java` code then the jsp will not be able to see it.  But usually JSP is the `V` part of the MVC paradigm, that is to say, the view part, and the `Controller` part should be in a servlet

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JSP location. tomcat server is not able to load JSP from its location and throwing 404.